# How do I configure the sending of json objects to Django Channels?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

How do I configure the sending of json objects to Django Channels? To ensure that when adding a new object in the admin panel, it immediately appeared on the front in real time. Maybe someone has any examples. Would be very grateful.

There is a Factory object:

models.py

```
class Factory(models.Model):

     OBJECT_CHOICES = (
            ('Завод', 'Завод'),
            ('Вышка', 'Вышка'),
            ('Хранилище', 'Хранилище'),
            ('АЗС', 'АЗС')
        )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=OBJECT_CHOICES, default = '')
    address = YmapCoord(max_length=200, start_query=u'Россия', size_width=500, size_height=500, unique = True)
```

When a GET request is made to / getFactory /, JSON type is issued

```
[
   {
    "title": "factory",
    "choice": "Завод",
    "address": [
        55.744607932133505,
        48.99357300960071
    ]
   }
]
```

Comment: DId you solve this question?

Comment: No, I used your help to get the update. I configured the users to connect and disconnect. I prescribed routes for them. I opened a new WebSocket in the .js file of the main page, but I did not get it. It seems to me that there is still something to be assigned to the function for getting objects, so that when updating it sends a request to the declared url. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @DaniilMashkin up, sorry

Comment: Add your consumer and html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a [consumer](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html#websocketconsumer) and you should define `groups` field there.

> A WebsocketConsumer’s channel will automatically be added to (on connect) and removed from (on disconnect) any groups whose names appear in the consumer’s groups class attribute.

Then your front-end should connect to the consumer somehow and listen for updates. 
Once that is done you can send new messages from any place of your project. For example, from `post_save` signal.

```
from channels import Group
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Factory)
def notify_group(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        group_name = 'your group'
        Group(group_name).send({'text': 'message or object'})
```